# SQLite3 multithreading

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, sqlite

I have just began learning SQLite3. I have been reading this article http://dev.yorhel.nl/doc/sqlaccess that describes the different multithreading mechanisms to adopt with SQLite3.
Could anyone please tell me which approach is the most accurate and performant one ?

Comment: Are you using multple threads? Do you share connections or statements between threads?

Comment: After reading the article i decided to use a single serial dispatch queue that will perform all the fetch/update operations. I also decided to use only one SHARED database connection. Will the serial queue prevent all the multithreading conflicts and issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single serial dispatch queue will prevent all issues, as far as the database is concerned.

(You still have to manage concurrent accesses from the rest of your program to the queue.)

Comment: Yes i believe that this is the best approach to follow in order to make a well multithreaded SQLite application. With a single DB connection and a single serial dispatch queue you can almost perfectly perform a nice multithreaded access to the DB.